# Adding reference to my project but cant use it

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I'm Developing a Windows CE device application in C#.

When I add reference **System.Deployment** to my project it should let me add **Namespace: System.Drawing.Printing**.

When I expand References I can see **System.Deployment** there, but when i want to add **Namespace: System.Drawing.Printing** i get error:

> *The type or namespace name 'Printing' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Drawing' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*

What am I doing wrong?

I have done some research but can't find a solution.

Comment: You are missing the namespace `System.Drawing`, `System.Drawing.Printing` can not work without `System.Drawing`

Comment: I downloaded example code and there is no System.Drawing namespace in there. So I think you can use System.Drawing.Printing without System.Drawing. I'll try it and see if it works.

Comment: Also this is WindowsCE I don't think `System.Drawing` even exists there let alone `System.Drawing.Printing`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add reference to `System.Drawing` assembly instead of `System.Deployment`

Read more about this namespace at msdn [System.Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx)

[image]

Comment: Curious: How did you get that theme working? or is this blend?

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses VS2012, dark theme. Built into the IDE.

Comment: need to look more in the options then,  beautiful :)

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses note than green rectangle is still paint :)

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses Tools -> Options - General. I think. =)

Answer (score 1):

Just add [`System.Drawing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) namespace to your solution.